# test validator failed to start: blockstore error (on ubuntu)

Tags: solana-test-validator

While trying to run the test validator inside a ubuntu based docker container, I keep getting an error while trying to run the test validator.

The error message I get when I try to run the `solana-test-validator` command (both with, and without the `--reset` flag):

```
Ledger location: test-ledger
Log: test-ledger/validator.log
Error: failed to start validator: Failed to create ledger at test-ledger: blockstore error
```

What could be the cause? I'm thinking it maybe some sort of missing dependency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it! The thing that did it was to install the `bzip2` package in ubuntu. The solana validator uses it for compression some of the ledger data.

```
sudo apt install bzip2
```

Note: Many other people have reported in various places online that resetting the validator worked for them: (which you can do when your run the startup command)

```
solana-test-validator --reset
```

And some have also said this did not work, but they removed the entire ledger directory and that solved it for them.